# Where and How to store and Retrieve Images in Web Application?

Tags: java, angularjs, hibernate, spring-mvc, e-commerce

Which is the recommended way to store images .Should it be stored in server or in cloud and how should it be retrieved to the client side in an Ecommerce web application which uses angular JS in client side and  spring MVC4 hibernate 4
in server side.
1]DO I have to convert each image into bytes and send it to client from server with a seperate servlet image handler
2]IS there any other way
3] i am able to get the images in client side to server and server can store the images in public directory like d drive but I am not able to access a public directory which is situated in my d drive within client side What should I do?

Comment: what is wrong with the standard `<img src=...>` tag

Comment: cannot access the dynamically loaded image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store images anywhere you want depending on its security concern. If those images can be publicly accessible you can send its url/path in response which can be set as `src` by angular js app.
But if its a security concerned and it will be according to role rights implementation then you should return as `multipart/form-data` (base64) in response.
Later on this will be set as `src="data:image/png;base64,<YOUR_RESPONSE_DATA>`

Comment: Can i have an example code cause right now i have 1000 images and the images are dynamically loaded by vendors so when client tries to access the image since the war file is already deployed i cannot access the stored images in tomcat 7  so i want to know whether i have to send the images one by one from server to client or simply sending the url where the image is located is enough

Comment: I think you can try by sending urls of images. If you dont have security concerns over images then you can directly share url of images inside a public directory. Also set directory accessibility to false.

Comment: But i am not able to access a public directory witch is situated in my d drive within client side  .